# Wildcard in MapPageRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, webforms

I have a webforms-project where I use System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.MapPageRoute to rewrite URLs but I have a problem with a few dynamic URLs. My URL could look like this;

```
/folder/city-1-2-something.aspx
```

and the MapPageRoute for this looks like this

```
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("CompanyCity", "folder/city-{id}-{pid}-{title}.aspx", "~/mypage.aspx");
```

But I have realized that some URLs could look like this

```
/folder/city-2-2-something-something.aspx
/folder/city-2-2-something-something-something.aspx
/folder/city-2-2-something-something-something-something.aspx
```

and these are not cought correctly by my routing - the first example will end up with the results id = 2-2 and pid = something instead of id = 2 and pid = 2.

The {title} is not important - only {id} and {pid} are used. I have several similar routes to specific folders, so as far as I can se I cannot use a catch all. But how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple RouteConfig below contains a TestRoute that matches exactly what you need. And nothing more,so it is in a sense quite bad code.

But the idea is that it is now possible to use regular expressions which can quite easily match your needs. (The named groups "id" `(?<id>\d)` and "pid" `(?<pid>\d)` only matches digits (`\d`) why they will only match until next dash.)

Hope it can be of some inspiration.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace InfosoftConnectSandbox
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        class TestRoute : RouteBase
        {
            Regex re = new Regex(@"folder/city-(?<pid>\d)-(?<id>\d)-.*");

            public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                var data = new RouteData();

                var url = httpContext.Request.Url.ToString();

                if (!re.IsMatch(url))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                foreach (Match m in re.Matches(url))
                {
                    data.Values["pid"] = m.Groups["pid"].Value;
                    data.Values["id"] = m.Groups["id"].Value;
                }

                data.RouteHandler = new PageRouteHandler("~/mypage.aspx");

                return data;
            }

            public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
            {
                return new VirtualPathData(this, "~/mypage.aspx");
            }
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Add(new TestRoute());

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```