# Re-mapping folders in a asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting an asp.net webforms website type project to an asp.net mvc web application. I want to keep all the changes to a minimum.

The pages and its subfolders are right at the top of the project folder and there are hundreds of them.

Now, in the new web application, I want to move them to a subfolder, let's call it WebForms.

Is there a way at runtime to run the pages as they ran before, i.e. at the root of the application folder?

Before I had: http://localhost:54321/Page1.aspx. Page1.aspx was stored in the website project root folder.

In the new project structure I have the disk:

```
<project folder>
   WebForms
      Page1.aspx
```

This works: http://localhost:54321/WebForms/Page1.aspx, but I want to somehow map it to http://localhost:54321/Page1.aspx.

Is it doable? I use IIS Express for development and IIS 7.5 for test/production deployment. I want to avoid having to change the image and other content urls - as you can imagine moving the pages to the subfolder breaks some of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to map all requests to `/something.aspx` so they go instead to `WebForms\something.aspx`, you can probably just use the following route rule.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
   "Other Web Pages",
   "{pagename}.aspx",
   "~/WebForms/{pagename}.aspx");
```

Alternately, if you need more advanced scenarios, you could use a custom class that derives from `RouteBase` and use a `RegEx` to match for and map the route, similar to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245058/wildcard-in-mappageroute)

```
public class WebFormsRoute : RouteBase
{
      Regex re = new Regex(@"^/(?<page>\w+)\.aspx", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
      {
         var data = new RouteData();


         var url = httpContext.Request.FilePath;

         if (!re.IsMatch(url))
         {
            return null;
         }

         var m = re.Match(url);

         data.RouteHandler = new PageRouteHandler("~/WebForms/" + m.Groups["page"].Value + ".aspx");

         return data;
      }

}
```

And then add it to your route collection in `RouteConfig`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


     routes.Add(new WebFormsRoute());

     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
  }

}
```